# Script that adds a row with formulas from previous columns while also sorting

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a script that I enter B2, B5, E2, & E5 that will add it to the bottom row of the list. I'm needing to add the formulas that are all different from columns E:Y along with it and be able to sort column A (alphabetically). Can Anyone help?

```
function addcustomer() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var customersSS    = ss.getSheetByName("customers"); //customers Sheet
   
  //Input Values
  var values = [[customersSS.getRange("B2").getValue(),
                 customersSS.getRange("B5").getValue(),
                 customersSS.getRange("E2").getValue(),
                 customersSS.getRange("E5").getValue(),]];
  
  customersSS.getRange(customersSS.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues(values);


 }
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried to adapt the script to your needs and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. You said "I'm needing to add the formulas that are all different from columns E:Y along with it". It's not clear (at least to me) what this actually means. Would you please edit your question to be more detailed/specific. Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet and we don't know what you data looks like. It would be helpful to supply some test data as well as an example of how a successful outcome would appear.